# Google Chrome blocking <img>

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm developing a QR Code tag. This tag will be generated on the browser with the QR code and some written details.

Currently I'm stuck because the image displays as intended on Firefox and MS Edge, but not on G Chrome. I've already reconfigure the browser to load any image, but the problem persists.

---

This is the line of code:

```html
<img class = "qr_code_imagem" src="http://datamatrix.kaywa.com/img.php?s=5&d=asdf.png" alt="datamatrix"/>
```

The `s` parameter is the size for the qr code and the `d` is the message that has to be decoded.

Can anyone give me some tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the console, it shows that `ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` which is an SSL error.

[Console Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDoXi.png)

Please look at this URL: https://www.ssl2buy.com/wiki/how-to-fix-err_cert_common_name_invalid-in-chrome

If you copy and paste the URL in the image tag into chrome, it works properly.

Enabling SSL on your site should solve your problem (Use a free SSL like Let's Encrypt or Zero SSL for testing)